# Populate JTable from a Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, swing, hashtable, jtable

I have a function which gets a key from the user and generates a Hashtable (on a pattern specified by the key). After creating a Hashtable, I would like to populate a JTable so that each each column represents a key and every rows represents the values associated with the key. I tried everything but couldn't get this work. I'm not creating the table from within the constructor as I need to get input from the user.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [How to Use Tables: Creating a Table Model](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data).

> The JTable constructor used by
>   SimpleTableDemo creates its table
>   model with code like this:

```
new AbstractTableModel() {
    public String getColumnName(int col) {
        return columnNames[col].toString();
    }
    public int getRowCount() { return rowData.length; }
    public int getColumnCount() { return columnNames.length; }
    public Object getValueAt(int row, int col) {
        return rowData[row][col];
    }
    public boolean isCellEditable(int row, int col)
        { return true; }
    public void setValueAt(Object value, int row, int col) {
        rowData[row][col] = value;
        fireTableCellUpdated(row, col);
    }
}
```

You basically have to wrap your hashtable in the above manner. Here's an example.

```
package eed3si9n.hashtabletable;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.util.Enumeration;
import java.util.Hashtable;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.AbstractTableModel;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.Dimension;

public class MainForm extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private JPanel jContentPane = null;  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="23,38"
    private JScrollPane m_scrollPane = null;
    private JTable m_table = null;
    private Hashtable<String, String> m_hash = null;
    private JButton m_btnAdd = null;    

    /**
     * This is the default constructor
     */
    public MainForm() {
        super();
        initialize();
        m_hash = new Hashtable<String, String>();
        m_hash.put("Dog", "Bow");
    }

    private void onButtonPressed() {
        m_hash.put("Cow", "Moo");
        m_table.revalidate();
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes this
     * 
     * @return void
     */
    private void initialize() {
        this.setSize(409, 290);
        this.setTitle("JFrame");
        this.setContentPane(getJContentPane());
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes jContentPane
     * 
     * @return javax.swing.JPanel
     */
    private JPanel getJContentPane() {
        if (jContentPane == null) {
            jContentPane = new JPanel();
            jContentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            jContentPane.setSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            jContentPane.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
            jContentPane.add(getM_scrollPane(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
            jContentPane.add(getM_btnAdd(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        }
        return jContentPane;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes m_scrollPane 
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JScrollPane  
     */
    private JScrollPane getM_scrollPane() {
        if (m_scrollPane == null) {
            m_scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
            m_scrollPane.setViewportView(getM_table());
        }
        return m_scrollPane;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes m_table  
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JTable   
     */
    private JTable getM_table() {
        if (m_table == null) {
            m_table = new JTable();
            m_table.setModel(new AbstractTableModel(){
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public int getColumnCount() {
        return 2;
    }

    public int getRowCount() {
        return m_hash.size();
    }

    public String getColumnName(int column) {
        if (column == 0) {
            return "Animal";
        } else {
            return "Sound";
        }
    }

    public Object getValueAt(int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        if (columnIndex == 0) {
            return getKey(rowIndex);
        } else {
            return m_hash.get(getKey(rowIndex));
        } // if-else

    }

    private String getKey(int a_index) {
        String retval = "";
        Enumeration<String> e = m_hash.keys();
        for (int i = 0; i < a_index + 1; i++) {
            retval = e.nextElement();
        } // for

        return retval;
    }

            });
        }
        return m_table;
    }

    /**
     * This method initializes m_btnAdd 
     *  
     * @return javax.swing.JButton  
     */
    private JButton getM_btnAdd() {
        if (m_btnAdd == null) {
            m_btnAdd = new JButton();
            m_btnAdd.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(34, 30));
            m_btnAdd.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                    onButtonPressed();
                }
            });
        }
        return m_btnAdd;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event-dispatching thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                MainForm frame = new MainForm();
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}  //  @jve:decl-index=0:visual-constraint="10,10"
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, avoid `Hashtable`, go straight for `Map`. In this case there two potential standard implementations you mights want: `LinkedHashMap` can retain the order that the entries were added; `TreeMap`, a `SortedMap`/`NavigableMap`, will sort the results (order of which can be determined by a `Comparator`. Alternatively you might want a form of `Map` that fire events or also provides a `TableModel`.

If you want a one time conversion from the `Map` to table, then it's pretty straightforward.

```
public static TableModel toTableModel(Map<?,?> map) {
    DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(
        new Object[] { "Key", "Value" }, 0
    );
    for (Map.Entry<?,?> entry : map) {
        model.addRow(new Object[] { entry.getKey(), entry.getValue() });
    }
    return model;
}
```

Then just create the `JTable` with this pre-populated model.

(Disclaimer: I've not tested or so much as compiled this code.)

To keep the `Map` and `TableModel` synchronized is more code. Generally it's best to avoid duplicating state whereever possible. Write a class that exposes itself as both a `Map` and a `TableModel`. You could go more disjoint by having a `Map` that fires events and a `TableModel` that adapts the `Map` (although note that `Map` does not have random access based on index, so you'll need to be iether clever or slow for large maps).

Going the other way, a simpler approach would be to add the data straight to a `DefaultTableModel` and not using a `Map` at all.